# Api testing issue with Json

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

Im new to the Django Rest Framework i think i did the serializer thing and views correctly, and it looks like this:

```
class MyAnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyAnimal
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'name', 'animal', 'race', 'birthyear',
                  'color', 'sex', 'height', 'father', 'mother', 'doc_num',)
```

```
class MyAnimalFormApi(APIView):

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = MyAnimalSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Now when i try to test it with Postman

```
{ "data": { "name": "name", "animal": "dog"}, }
```

i get {
"detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 47 (char 46)"
}

but it is enclosed in double quotes.
Do you have any idea what's wrong or how to make it accessible only via {"name": "", "animal": ""} instead of nesting dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the trailing comma.

```py
>>> json.loads('{ "data": { "name": "name", "animal": "dog"}, }')
...
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 47 (char 46)
```

Should be this instead.

```
{ "data": { "name": "name", "animal": "dog"} }
```

```py
>>> json.loads('{ "data": { "name": "name", "animal": "dog"} }')
{'data': {'name': 'name', 'animal': 'dog'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error i believe, is because you need to dump the json data before you send it in your request.

```
data = json.dumps(payload)
```

Where payload is your data dictionary. This will convert it into a string.